# Flink Custom Trigger giving Unexpected Output

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to create a `Trigger` which gets fired in 20 seconds for the first time and in every five seconds after that. I have used `GlobalWindows` and a custom `Trigger`

```scala
val windowedStream = valueStream
                          .keyBy(0)
                          .window(GlobalWindows.create())
                          .trigger(TradeTrigger.of())
```

Here is the code in `TradeTrigger`:

```java
@PublicEvolving
public class TradeTrigger<W extends Window> extends Trigger<Object, W> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static boolean flag=false;
    static long ctime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private TradeTrigger() {
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(
            Object arg0,
            long arg1,
            W arg2,
            org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext arg3)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(flag == false){
            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-ctime) >= 20000){
               flag = true;
               ctime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               return TriggerResult.FIRE;
            }
            return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
        } else {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-ctime) >= 5000){
                ctime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return TriggerResult.FIRE;
            }
            return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(
            long arg0,
            W arg1,
            org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext arg2)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(
            long arg0,
            W arg1,
            org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext arg2)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }


    public static <W extends Window> TradeTrigger<W> of() {
        return new TradeTrigger<>();
    }

}
```

So basically, when `flag` is `false`, i.e. the first time, the `Trigger` should get fired in 20 seconds and set the `flag` to `true`. From the next time, it should get fired every 5 seconds.

The problem I am facing is, I am getting only one message in the output every time the `Trigger` is fired. That is, I get a single message after 20 seconds and single messages in every five seconds.
I am expecting twenty messages in the output on each triggering.

If I use `.timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))` and create a time window of five seconds, I get 20 messages in output every 5 seconds.
Please help me get this code right. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with the help of the answer from Fabian and Flink mailing lists.
Stored the state in a `ValueState` variable through the `TriggerContext`. Checked the variable in `onEvent()` method and if it was the first time, registered a `processingTimeTimer` for 20 seconds more than the current time and updated the state. In the `onProcessingTime` method, registered another `ProcessingTimeTimer` for 5 seconds more than current time, updated the state and fired the `Window`.

Comment: Could you please update the answer with the updated code? That would  be really helpful

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues with your Trigger implementation:

1. You should never store the state of a function in a static variable. Flink does not isolate user processes in JVMs. Instead it uses a single JVM per TaskManager and starts multiple threads. Hence, your static boolean flag is shared across multiple instances of triggers. You should store the flag Flink's `ValueState` interface which is accessible from the `TriggerContext`. Flink will take care to checkpoint your state and recover it in case of a failure.
2. `Trigger.onEvent()` is only called when a new event arrives. So it cannot be used to trigger a Window computation at a specific time. Instead you should register an event time timer or processing time timer (again via the `TriggerContext`). The timer will call `Trigger.onEventTime()` or `Trigger.onProcessingTime()` respectively. Whether to use event or processing time depends on your use case.

Comment: Thank you again Fabian. But I need to know how this can be done programmatically.
1. How do I store my flag variable in the `ValueState` and how do I access it?
2. Do I need to write the logic in `onProcessingTime()` or `onEventTime()` overridden methods in my `Trigger`?
3. What is the correct syntax to register a timer via trigger context?